# Trouble with 2d array to make freeze one object and duplicate said object 90 pixels to the right

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make it so that when I hit space, I can pause a moving rectangle stack on one position, and duplicate it 90 pixels to the right and complete the same motion. This should happen across the columns (grids) on the canvas. I'm thinking a 2D array will be needed, but I am stuck on how to do this.

If anyone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

```
 float loc;
 float sizeW;
 float sizeH;
 float dir;
 boolean moving = true;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  loc = 0;
  dir = (float)height/720;
  sizeW = (float)width/14.2;
  sizeH = (float)height/8;    
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  Rectangle();
  grid();
}

void Rectangle() {
  fill(255, 147, 79);
  stroke(0);

  int steppedPos = (int)(loc/sizeH+0.5);
  rect(0, steppedPos*sizeH, sizeW, sizeH);

  for (int i =0; i<90*4; i+=90) {
    rect(0, steppedPos*sizeH+i, sizeW, sizeH);
  }
      if (moving) {
       loc = loc + dir;
    if (loc + sizeH + 270 > height || loc < 0) {
      dir = dir * -1;
      loc = loc + dir;
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    moving = !moving;    
  }
}    

void grid() {
  for (int i=0; i<width; i+=90) {
    line(i, 0, i, height);
  }
  for (int j=0; j<height; j+=90) {
    line(0, j, width, j);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a quick way of duplicating the columns to the right.
What I'm doing is adding 90 to `valueX` every time you hit the spacebar. `valueX` then will be gone throw in the nested for-loop.

I hope that this is the output you wanted! (If not then leave a comment and I'll try to fix it.)

```
    float loc;
    float sizeW;
    float sizeH;
    float dir;
    float valueX = 0;
    boolean moving = true;

    void setup() {
      size(1280, 720);
      loc = 0;
      dir = (float)height/720;
      sizeW = (float)width/14.2;
      sizeH = (float)height/8;
    }

    void draw() {
      background(255);
      Rectangle();
      grid();
    }

    void Rectangle() {
      fill(255, 147, 79);
      stroke(0);

      int steppedPos = (int)(loc/sizeH+0.5);
    //  rect(0, steppedPos*sizeH, sizeW, sizeH);

      for (int i =0; i<90*4; i+=90) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= valueX; j+= 90){
        rect(0 + j, steppedPos*sizeH+i, sizeW, sizeH);
        }
      }
      if (moving) {
        loc = loc + dir;
        if (loc + sizeH + 270 > height || loc < 0) {
          dir = dir * -1;
          loc = loc + dir;
        }
      }
    }

    void keyPressed() {
      if (key == ' ') {
        moving = !moving;
        valueX += 90;
      }
    }    

    void grid() {
      for (int i=0; i<width; i+=90) {
        line(i, 0, i, height);
      }
      for (int j=0; j<height; j+=90) {
        line(0, j, width, j);
      }
    }
```

Your idea with the a 2d array isn't bad, but the problem is that arrays have a fixed size. So what you would like to use is an ArrayList for the x-axis and an Array for the y-axis (as long as this stays a fixed size). This would look similar to this:

```
    ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

With this method you could look at Object Orientation, just to clean up things. (If you'd like to I can show you how your code would look like object-oriented)

Greetings and good Luck!